# Plotting 4 plots on 1 page, with a common legend in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have the following plot:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  FunctionClass = factor(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I",     "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "Y", "Z"), levels=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "Y", "Z")),
  legend = c("A: RNA processing and modification", "B: Chromatin structure and dynamics", "C: Energy production and conversion", "D: Cell cycle control, cell division, chromosome partitioning", "E: Amino acid transport and metabolism", "F: Nucleotide transport and metabolism", "G: Carbohydrate transport and metabolism", "H: Coenzyme transport and metabolism", "I: Lipid transport and metabolism", "J: Translation, ribosomal structure and biogenesis", "K: Transcription", "L: Replication, recombination and repair", "M: Cell wall/membrane/envelope biogenesis", "N: Cell motility", "O: Posttranslational modification, protein turnover, chaperones", "P: Inorganic ion transport and metabolism", "Q: Secondary metabolites biosynthesis, transport and catabolism", "R: General function prediction only", "S: Function unknown", "T: Signal transduction mechanisms", "U: Intracellular trafficking, secretion, and vesicular transport", "V: Defense mechanisms", "W: Extracellular structures", "Y: Nuclear structure", "Z: Cytoskeleton"),
  Differential_Abundance=c(2.1,2.2,3.4,3.3,2,1.1,0.1,0.1,-0.3,-0.9,3,2.1,-0.3,-0.9,-2,-1.2,-0.4,-0.5,-3,-2,-0.3,-2.1,-1.3,-2.2,-3),
  Differential_Abundance2=c(2.1,2.2,3.4,3.3,2,1.1,0.1,0.1,-0.3,-0.9,3,2.1,-0.3,-0.9,-2,-1.2,-0.4,-0.5,-3,-2,-0.3,-2.1,-1.3,-2.2,-3),
  Differential_Abundance3=c(2.1,2.2,3.4,3.3,2,1.1,0.1,0.1,-0.3,-0.9,3,2.1,-0.3,-0.9,-2,-1.2,-0.4,-0.5,-3,-2,-0.3,-2.1,-1.3,-2.2,-3),
  Differential_Abundance4=c(2.1,2.2,3.4,3.3,2,1.1,0.1,0.1,-0.3,-0.9,3,2.1,-0.3,-0.9,-2,-1.2,-0.4,-0.5,-3,-2,-0.3,-2.1,-1.3,-2.2,-3)
)
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=FunctionClass, y=Differential_Abundance, fill=legend))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), colour="seashell")
p + guides (fill = guide_legend(ncol = 1))+
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(levels(dat$FunctionClass))) +
  xlab("COG Class") +
  ylab("Differential Abundance (Treated/Untreated)")
```

Now, I want 4 similar plots (But with 4 "Differential_Abundance" values, but same y-axis) on the same page, with 4 separate labels (A, B, C and D). I guess, I have to move the legend to the bottom as well, as it would take up too much space in the site.

Anyway of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure but I think `facet`ing might be a good way to do it.

Comment: Cool, care to elaborate? I am not very experienced with R.

Comment: [Docs page on facetting](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_wrap.html)

Comment: Where would the labels come from? Differential abundance is numeric, but you're referring to A, B, C, and D groups

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faceting is a good way to include multiple plots that share a common legend.

First, I'll augment the data to include a `label`. (I'll use random data to show it being different in the faceted plot.)

```r
set.seed(42)
dataug <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), function(lbl) {
  transform(dat, label = lbl,
            Differential_Abundance = Differential_Abundance + runif(nrow(dat), -2, 1))
}))
# or blindly and less-interestingly
dataug <- rbind(transform(data, label="A"), # first frame
                transform(data, label="B"), # second frame
                transform(data, label="C"), # ...
                transform(data, label="D"))
```

In your case, you might already have it but as separate frames, in which case you likely need to add the `label=` manually to each frame and then combine them into one frame using `rbind`. (`ggplot2` really prefers things in a "long" format, try to mimic what I've done with `dataaug`.)

From here, just `facet_wrap` or `facet_grid`:

```r
p <- ggplot(data=dataug, aes(x=FunctionClass, y=Differential_Abundance, fill=legend))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), colour="seashell")
p + guides (fill = guide_legend(ncol = 1))+
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(levels(dat$FunctionClass))) +
  xlab("COG Class") +
  ylab("Differential Abundance (Treated/Untreated)") +
  facet_wrap(~ label)                                               # the only addition
```

[image: faceted plot]

Some notes:

- `facet_*(..., scales=)` allows the x-axis and/or y-axis to be "free", otherwise it is assumed that all axes will be the same between facets. (If you have largely disparate data, you'll want to use this, otherwise it's typically best to not change its default.
- `facet_wrap(..., nrow=, ncol=)` allows your to define the width/height (number of cells)
- `facet_grid(xfacet ~ yfacet, ...)` allows you to facet by two variables, one on each facet-axis. Likely not a player given your data and explanation.

---

**Edit**: given your data format, it's best to convert from a "wide" to a "long" format. There are plenty of resources on StackOverflow for this topic, but in short I recommend `tidyr::gather` for this task:

```r
dataug <- tidyr::gather(dat, label, Differential_Abundance, -FunctionClass, -legend)
```

This will work with my augmented plot code above.

Comment: Hi!! Thank you very much for your response, it is very helpful!
I think I understand most of it, including the labeling, however, I'm a bit unsure on how you now append your data. If I have my data in the format:
Differential_Abundance=c(2.1,2.2,3.4,3.3,2,1.1,0.1,0.1,-0.3,-0.9,3,2.1,-0.3,-0.9,-2,-1.2,-0.4,-0.5,-3,-2,-0.3,-2.1,-1.3,-2.2,-3)
Could you show it, where you just use that data 4 times?

Comment: If the data for your other datasets (allegedly "B" through "D") are just separate frames, then `rbind(dat1, dat2, dat3, dat4)` will produce a single aggregated frame. If you need to assign a "label" to each (to indicate the respective frame), then that should be done before `rbind`.

Comment: See me edit for how one might combine four frames, assigning the label as-you-go. If the label is already set in each, then really just `dataug <- rbind(dat1, dat2, dat3, dat4)`.

Comment: Okay, so I edited my question. If my data.frame looks like that in the question. What do I do to use that instead?

Comment: See my edit. The "wide" versus "long" discussion is covered well in several other SO answers, so I won't go into the rationale or other ways to play with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "ggarrange" from "ggpubr" package to join multiple sub-plots in the same plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
dat <- data.frame(
  FunctionClass = factor(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I",     "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "Y", "Z"), levels=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "Y", "Z")),
  legend = c("A: RNA processing and modification", "B: Chromatin structure and dynamics", "C: Energy production and conversion", "D: Cell cycle control, cell division, chromosome partitioning", "E: Amino acid transport and metabolism", "F: Nucleotide transport and metabolism", "G: Carbohydrate transport and metabolism", "H: Coenzyme transport and metabolism", "I: Lipid transport and metabolism", "J: Translation, ribosomal structure and biogenesis", "K: Transcription", "L: Replication, recombination and repair", "M: Cell wall/membrane/envelope biogenesis", "N: Cell motility", "O: Posttranslational modification, protein turnover, chaperones", "P: Inorganic ion transport and metabolism", "Q: Secondary metabolites biosynthesis, transport and catabolism", "R: General function prediction only", "S: Function unknown", "T: Signal transduction mechanisms", "U: Intracellular trafficking, secretion, and vesicular transport", "V: Defense mechanisms", "W: Extracellular structures", "Y: Nuclear structure", "Z: Cytoskeleton"),
  Differential_Abundance=c(2.1,2.2,3.4,3.3,2,1.1,0.1,0.1,-0.3,-0.9,3,2.1,-0.3,-0.9,-2,-1.2,-0.4,-0.5,-3,-2,-0.3,-2.1,-1.3,-2.2,-3)
)



p <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=FunctionClass, y=Differential_Abundance, fill=legend))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), colour="seashell")

p <- p + 
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(levels(dat$FunctionClass))) +
  xlab("COG Class") +
  ylab("Differential Abundance (Treated/Untreated)") + labs(color = '')

p1 <- p
p2 <- p
p3 <- p
p4 <- p

ggarrange(p1,p2,p3,p4, nrow = 1, common.legend = T, legend.position = 'top')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, this is also a cool way of doing it!